# Dagger 2 - Can't initialize

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

When I compile my Android project, I catch such error:

*Error:(15, 13) error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
android.content.Context is provided at com......di.components.AppComponent.getContext()*

My component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    Context getContext();
    DataManager getDataManager();
}
```

My module:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
    protected final Application mApplication;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        mApplication = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    @Singleton
    Context provideContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataManager provideDataManager() {
        return new DataManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: you have `ApplicationContext` annotation in module, it should be removed, since you already have `Singleton` scope annotation

Comment: This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30552481/context-cannot-be-provided-without-an-provides-annotated-method-but-it-is might be of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your component says it can provide a `Context`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
interface AppComponent {
  Context getContext();
}
```

When all it knows about is a `@ApplicationContext Context` (notice the qualifier?):

```
@Module
class AppModule {

  @Provides
  @Singleton
  @ApplicationContext
  Context provideContext() {
    return mApplication;
  }
}
```

---

You can either remove the `@ApplicationContext` qualifier and just provide a `Context` from your module, which could get in the way if you try to also provide your activities context, or you keep your qualifier and actually provide the *qualified* context:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class})
interface AppComponent {
  @ApplicationContext
  Context getContext();
}
```

If you try to use / inject the application context you will also need to use the qualifier:

```
@ApplicationContext @Inject Context mContext;
```